# Outbound link creating a bad request only when clicked directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, https, hyperlink

Got a weird one, where a specific link (to an article on Medium) keeps giving me a 404 error, but only when clicked directly.  If I click 'open in new tab', or 'copy link address' and paste it, or even copy the url from the bad 404 request and paste it into a new tab/window - all of those work.

The link is on this page - http://www.welivecontent.com/posts/confessions-of-an-ex-tech-journalist (just click on the title).

The issue is cross-browser (i've tried in Firefox, Safari and Chrome).

It seems to be on any link to the site 'Medium' as I've tried tried a couple more links.

It's not specifically as https issue, as other outbound links to https redirects do work.

I use the gems 'metainspector', 'open-uri' and 'open_uri_redirections' to parse submitted urls.

Has anyone else run into this issue before?  Or could someone help with pointers on how to debug it?

Sorry if the information is a bit sparse, but I'm unsure what else would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your link is actually making a POST request to the linked page, not a GET request. The routes must be setup to only expect a GET request, which seems right.